# Removing duplicates from the 'div' inside the input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the duplicates inside the div i am  loading the input type values that values i am  getting from csv and that values are storing in `cells[0],cells[1],cells[2]` but i am loading that values into the input

```
"<input type='checkbox' class ='chk'   name='locationthemes' onclick='pandu();' value ="+cells[0]+"> " +cells[0]+ " </input><br>"); in that i am getting duplicates items how can i remove "
ex:<div id="checkboxes" style="display: block;">
   <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="locationthemes" onclick="pandu();" value="GreatLakes"> GreatLakes <br><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="locationthemes" onclick="pandu();" value="GreatLakes"> GreatLakes </div>
```

I have tried below mention code but not workin

```
var seen = {};
        $('#checkboxes').each(function() {
            var txt = $(this).text();
            if (seen[txt])
                $(this).remove();
            else
                seen[txt] = true;
        });
```

Comment: store the values from csv into an array and remove duplicates then create checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following https://jsfiddle.net/64xvLfjm/1/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click" class="Button" />
  </div>

  <div class="chkboxs">

  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnClick').click(function () {

        var myArr = ["abc","bbb","ccc","aaa","bbb","ccc"];
        var newArr = $.unique(myArr);

        for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
          $(".chkboxs").append("<input type='checkbox'>"+newArr[i]+"<br>");
        }

      });
});
```